# How to share JWT through 2 React.js Frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, jwt

I have 2 frontends with the same origin domain. Then how would I use cookie for that operation? Once user logged into the 1st frontend, then user must be able to get the JWT used in the 1st website whenever user log in.

For example, we are able to get into `mail.google.com` without logging in once we are logged in `account.google.com`.

Comment: Are you asking to share the `JWT` token across multiple domains (frontends you mean)?

Comment: If i understood correctly, do it just like how Oauth works. On success redirect user to 2nd domain with jwt token in url param, let 2nd domain server verify the token and allow if its valid.

Comment: Backend must be able to validate token no matter from where it is getting the request. But main problem would be here is that if user logged into one frontend then how you would make that token available to other frontend. You cannot use local storage for that purpose. One thing that you can use is cookie if your both frontends have same subdomain. For example: frontend1.xyz.com and frontend2.xyz.com. 
If domains are different then you have to check that how you can integrate SSO.

Comment: Don't just 'do like OAuth', implement OAuth2. It's designed for this and anything you can come up with will likely be worse or insecure.